# retrieve a word after a regular expression in shell script

Tags: regex, shell

I am trying to retrieve specific fields from a text file which has a metadata as follows:

```
project=XYZ; cell=ABC; strain=C3H; sex=F; age=PQR; treatment=None; id=MLN
```

And I have the following script for retrieving the field `'cell'`

```
while read line
do
cell="$(echo $line | cut -d";" -f7 )"
echo  $cell
fi
done < files.txt
```

However the following script retrieves the whole field as `cell=ABC` , whereas I just want the value `'ABC'` from the field, how do I retrieve the value after the regex, in the same line of code?

Comment: What shell are you using?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

If **extracting *one* value** (or, generally, a non-repeating set of values captured by distinct capture groups) is enough and you're running **`bash`, `ksh`, or `zsh`**, consider using the **regex-matching operator, `=~`**: `[[ string =~ regex ]]`:

<sup>Tip of the hat to @Adrian Frühwirth for the gist of the `ksh` and `zsh` solutions.</sup>

Sample input string:

```
string='project=XYZ; cell=ABC; strain=C3H; sex=F; age=PQR; treatment=None; id=MLN'
```

Shell-specific use of `=~` is discussed next; a multi-shell implementation of the `=~` functionality via a shell function can be found at the end.

---

#### bash

The special `BASH_REMATCH` array variable receives the results of the matching operation: element `0` contains the entire match, element `1` the first capture group's (parenthesized subexpression's) match, and so on.

`bash 3.2+`:

```
[[ $string =~ \ cell=([^;]+) ]] && cell=${BASH_REMATCH[1]} # -> $cell == 'ABC'
```

`bash 4.x`:
While the specific command above works, using regex literals in bash `4.x` is buggy, notably when involving word-boundary assertions `\<` and `\>` on Linux; e.g., `[[ a =~ \<a ]]` inexplicably doesn't match; workaround: *use an intermediate variable* (unquoted!): `re='\a'; [[ a =~ $re ]]` works (also on bash `3.2+`).

`bash 3.0 and 3.1` - or after setting `shopt -s compat31`:
*Quote* the regex to make it work:

```
[[ $string =~ ' cell=([^;]+)' ]] && cell=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}  # -> $cell == 'ABC'
```

---

#### ksh

The `ksh` syntax is the same as in `bash`, except:

- the name of the special array variable that contains the matched strings is `.sh.match` (you must enclose the name in `{...}` even when just implicitly referring to the first element with `${.sh.match}`):

```
[[ $string =~ \ cell=([^;]+) ]] && cell=${.sh.match[1]} # -> $cell == 'ABC'
```

---

#### zsh

The `zsh` syntax is also similar to bash, except:

- The regex *literal* must be *quoted* - for simplicity as a whole, or at least *some* shell metacharacters, such as `;`.

  - you may, but *needn't double-quote* a regex provided as a *variable* value.
  - Note how this quoting behavior differs fundamentally from that of bash 3.2+: `zsh` requires quoting only for syntax reasons and always treats the resulting string as a whole as a regex, whether it or parts of it were quoted or not.
- There are *2* variables containing the matching results:

  - `$MATCH` contains the *entire* matched string
  - array variable `$match` contains only the matches for the capture groups (note that `zsh` arrays start with index `1` and that you don't need to enclose the variable name in `{...}` to reference array elements)

```
 [[ $string =~ ' cell=([^;]+)' ]] && cell=$match[1] # -> $cell == 'ABC'
```

---

#### Multi-shell implementation of the `=~` operator as shell function `reMatch`

The following shell function abstracts away the differences between `bash`, `ksh`, `zsh` with respect to the `=~` operator; the matches are returned in array variable `${reMatches[@]}`.

As @Adrian Frühwirth notes, to write portable (across `zsh`, `ksh`, `bash`) code with this, you need to execute `setopt KSH_ARRAYS` in `zsh` so as to make its arrays start with index *`0`*; as a side effect, you also have to use the `${...[]}` syntax when referencing arrays, as in `ksh` and `bash`).

Applied to our example we'd get:

```sh
  # zsh: make arrays behave like in ksh/bash: start at *0*
[[ -n $ZSH_VERSION ]] && setopt KSH_ARRAYS

reMatch "$string" ' cell=([^;]+)' && cell=${reMatches[1]}
```

**Shell function:**

```sh
# SYNOPSIS
#   reMatch string regex
# DESCRIPTION
#   Multi-shell implementation of the =~ regex-matching operator;
#   works in: bash, ksh, zsh
#
#   Matches STRING against REGEX and returns exit code 0 if they match.
#   Additionally, the matched string(s) is returned in array variable ${reMatch[@]},
#   which works the same as bash's ${BASH_REMATCH[@]} variable: the overall
#   match is stored in the 1st element of ${reMatch[@]}, with matches for
#   capture groups (parenthesized subexpressions), if any, stored in the remaining
#   array elements.
#   NOTE: zsh arrays by default start with index *1*.
# EXAMPLE:
#   reMatch 'This AND that.' '^(.+) AND (.+)\.' # -> ${reMatch[@]} == ('This AND that.', 'This', 'that')
function reMatch {
  typeset ec
  unset -v reMatch # initialize output variable
  [[ $1 =~ $2 ]] # perform the regex test
  ec=$? # save exit code
  if [[ $ec -eq 0 ]]; then # copy result to output variable
    [[ -n $BASH_VERSION ]] && reMatch=( "${BASH_REMATCH[@]}" )
    [[ -n $KSH_VERSION ]]  && reMatch=( "${.sh.match[@]}" )
    [[ -n $ZSH_VERSION ]]  && reMatch=( "$MATCH" "${match[@]}" )
  fi
  return $ec
}
```

Note:

- `function reMatch` (as opposed to `reMatch()`) is used to declare the function, which is required for `ksh` to truly create local variables with `typeset`.

Comment: `ksh` and `zsh` have similar features, `ksh` uses the `.sh.match` variable to store the matches and `zsh` can use `$BASH_REMATCH` in compatibility mode or its own `MATCH` and `match` variables otherwise. As for `bash` the `=~` was introduced in `3.0-alpha` so is older than one would think and deserves to be used more often.

Comment: @AdrianFrühwirth Thanks much for this - I've incorporated your great tips; re bash compatibility mode in `zsh` - couldn't get this to work, at least on `zsh 5.0.2` on OS X 10.9.2: `$BASH_REMATCH` never gets set (and the regex had to be _quoted_ so as not to break parsing).

Comment: Ad `zsh`: You need to enable the feature first, e.g. `setopt KSH_ARRAYS BASH_REMATCH`, then it should work as expected. `KSH_ARRAYS` makes sure to start array indices with 0 and to "as closely mimic `ksh` arrays as possible". Disclaimer: I am not a `zsh` user, but I tried it and it works for me.

Comment: @AdrianFrühwirth: Ah, that was the missing piece; it works for me now too, but the caveat is that you still need to _quote_ a _literal_ regex (with variable references, it doesn't matter) - unlike in bash.

Comment: I just played around with this and you don't but you *do* need to escape the `;` to make it work so `zsh` parses the string on the RHS differently than `bash` and `ksh` which apparently makes the whole thing completely unportable across those shells even though they all provide the `=~` feature. The `bash` changelog mentions several "fixes" wrt/ the parsing of the regex string so I don't even want to dig deeper, the inconsistencies are probably vast :( FWIW, this works: `[[ $string =~ \ cell=([^\;]+) ]] && echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}` => `ABC`.

Comment: @AdrianFrühwirth: Thanks; I've updated the answer with a shell function that abstracts away the differences.

Comment: It doesn't work around the quoting issue but nice nonetheless. Another problem is that I still don't think you can actually use this semi-portably unless you set `KSH_ARRAYS` globally in your script because of the indexing problem (setting and unsetting `KSH_ARRAYS` before and after populating the array does not keep index `0` either, indexing "moves" with the option so to speak, which is kind of expected). *If* you set/rely upon `KSH_ARRAYS` then you need braces to refer to `${match[@]}` as a consequence. EDIT: Just noticed that you did add that as disclaimer (except for the braces) :-)

Comment: @AdrianFrühwirth Thanks. Re braces: I've added that to the disclaimer and also updated the "portable" snippet that demonstrates use of `reMatch()` to include `setopt KSH_ARRAYS`. I'm sure there are many more pitfalls when it comes to writing scripts that are portable across `zsh`, `ksh`, and `bash` (scripts that use more than just POSIX features). Thanks for all the help and feedback.

Comment: @AdrianFrühwirth: One more thought: by using a _function_ I thought I _was_ effectively working around the quoting issue, since the `=~` expression then invariable uses a _variable_ (parameter) reference.

Answer (score 3):

I would not use `cut`, since you cannot specify more than one delimiter.

If your `grep` supports `PCRE`, then you can do:

```
$ string='project=XYZ; cell=ABC; strain=C3H; sex=F; age=PQR; treatment=None; id=MLN'
$ grep -oP '(?<=cell=)[^;]+' <<< "$string"
ABC
```

You can use `sed`, which in simple terms can be done as -

```
$ sed -r 's/.*cell=([^;]+).*/\1/' <<< "$string"
ABC
```

Another option is to use `awk`. With that you can do the following by specifying list of delimiters you want to consider as field separators:

```
$ awk -F'[;= ]' '{print $5}' <<< "$string"
ABC
```

You can certainly put more checks by iterating over the line so that you don't have to hard-code to print 5th field.

Note that if your shell does not support here-string notation `<<<` then you can `echo` the variable and pipe it to the command.

```
$ echo "$string" | cmd
```

Comment: I was trying the awk command and I was wondering as to how to assign it to a variable, I have been trying to use grep command as well but I am not sure as to how to assign it to a variable.

Comment: @AishwaryaKulkarni: Use command substitution as follows: `cell=$(...)`; specifically: `cell=$(awk -F'[;= ]' '{print $5}' <<< "$string")`.

Comment: @AishwaryaKulkarni Just like you are doing it right now. `cell=$(...)`

Comment: I used cell= $(echo "$string" | awk -F'[=;]' '{print $5}') since <<"$string" is not supported however it is giving the output but is also giving command not found error.

Comment: @AishwaryaKulkarni: Remove the space after `=` - there must not be spaces before and after the `=` in shell variable assignments.

Comment: Oops that was a silly mistake, thanks for pointing it out! Its a success!!

Comment: @AishwaryaKulkarni Don't forget to mark the answer if it helped. You can do so by clicking the tick mark next to it. Doesn't have to be this one, anyone in particular that helped you the most. It just helps everyone know that your question has been resolved. `:)`

Answer (score 2):

Here's a native shell solution:

```
$ string='project=XYZ; cell=ABC; strain=C3H; sex=F; age=PQR; treatment=None; id=MLN'
$ cell=${string#*cell=}
$ cell=${cell%%;*}
$ echo "${cell}"
ABC
```

This removes the shortest leading match up to including `cell=` from the string, then removes the longest trailing match up to including the `;` leaving you with `ABC`.

Here's another solution which uses `read` to split the strings:

```
$ cat t.sh
#!/bin/bash

while IFS=$'; \t' read -ra attributes; do
    for foo in "${attributes[@]}"; do
        IFS='=' read -r key value <<< "${foo}"
        [ "${key}" = cell ] && echo "${value}"
    done
done <<EOF
foo=X;  cell=ABC;  quux=Z;
foo=X;  cell=DEF;  quux=Z;
EOF
```

.

```
$ ./t.sh
ABC
DEF
```

For solutions using external tools see @jaypal's excellent answer.

Comment: Don't you mean `IFS=$'= \t'`? I'm assuming it's not intentional to add the literal backslash character and `t` to the set.